# How to use this.state inside exported function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, state, bind

I'm trying to use `this.state` from the exported function inside the App component.
The bind method is not working. Any ideas?

**I tried:**

*inside error-handler.js*

```
    export function errorHandler() {
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

*inside App.js*

```
   ...

   import { errorHandler } from '../../helpers/error-handler';

   class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.errorHandler = errorHandler.bind(this);
   }

   ...
```

**The result when trying to run errorHandler() inside App.js:**

```
"Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.errorHandler = errorHandler.bind(this);
```

because you just exported function, it is not a part of your class yet

Comment: I edit this line and removed the "this" keyword after the assignment operator and still not working. any ideas?

Comment: No ideas as far as i dont understand what you mean 'still not working'...This line threw exception, i pointed why, now may you just call this.errorHandler() and it should work

Answer (score 0):

The `errorHandler` is just an exported function. So you have to bind the method like below.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.errorHandler = errorHandler.bind(this); // bind event
}
...
...

<input 
 {...props}
 onClick={e => this.errorHandler()} // call method
/>
```